# Can we "import" reputation from MO?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I gather that users who register on this site who already have a certain amount of reputation on StackOverflow get a "starting bonus" to their reputation here. Is there a good reason why this can't also be done for users coming across from MathOverflow?

Answer (score 5):

MO is a 1.0 site, using an earlier version of the SE software. There have been numerous discussions on this topic at meta.stackoverflow (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53796/should-rep-from-other-non-trilogy-se-1-0-sites-count-for-commitment-phase/53799#53799) for example), and the short answer is that for technical reasons this cannot happen unless MO becomes SE 2.0 compliant, which itself is [something under debate](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/454/linking-in-with-stackoverlow-al/).

Answer (score 4):

Given that the bonus is only 100, I think we should regard it instead as a compliment to the MOwers: obviously the SE team think that any MOwer coming here will do so well that they don't need a start-up, whereas those coming from SO need all the help they can get!